# Is adding @2x or @1x image required

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, uikit

If I have @3x image and all I need to do is downscale that image to create @2x and @1x, why am I required to add them? I see some UIImage functions just downscale @3x image on the device whereas other UIImage functions fail if @2x image is not there. I find it very time consuming to downscale so many images and add them to project every time. Is there a workaround?

Edit: To make it more clear, my question is UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile returns nil if I only supply @3x without supplying @2x. But UIImage imageNamed works. Is that normal, or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You only *need* one image. Using `@1x` / `@2x` / `@3x` allows you to provide different resolution image resource *if you want to*.

Comment: You don't need 1x images since it's highly unlikely your app supports such old devices. Most devices are 2x devices.

Comment: Kindly read through this document from Apple [Image Size and Resolution](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you need to do or how you are using the scaled images... or even if they are photos or icons.

If you are using these images as icons, add them to an asset folder.   Then the assets can be referenced by name within a control on a storyboard.   Easy.

For creating buttons, let’s say a 40x40 button, I create the icon, 40 x 40, in Inkpad and save the result as a PDF file.  Then I put that in an image asset and select the option for only one image.  Since it is a vector drawing, it scales up nice.

If you are using the same images in multiple apps, I would recommend creating an assets folder called something like **Common_Images** and just copy that folder from one app to another. Deliriously quick & easy,

I wrote a quick and simple app that lets the user pick a photo, type in the 1x width and height, press a button and done!   Doing this on a Simulator lets me quickly drag and drop these new scaled pics right into an image asset within Xcode.   Quick and simple.